# Global Accelerometer Axis (C#)

Tags: c#, accelerometer, gyroscope, motion-detection

So I have been searching everywhere for the past days and reading everything I could about the subject but I just can't figure this out.

I have a glove with an embedded gyroscope and an accelerometer. I'm working with its SDK in C# and all I need is a simple application that tells me the direction of movement (up, down, front, back, left, right). With the accelerometer I can do this but only if I keep the hand facing the same direction, because the accelerometer is operating in its local axis (following the left hand rule).

My question is, how do I use the gyroscope data to rotate the accelerometer axis so I can get the directions relative to the earth axis? I can access the rotation in quaternion form and the last thing I tried was using that quaternion to rotate the vector composed by the acceleration on the gyroscope, but the values I got were all over the place.

I've been trying to figure this out but it's really not my area of expertise and many of what I read just doesn't make sense.. It's the first time I'm working with these type of sensors and what I need seems like a simple task..

**Example of the problem:**

Right glove, palm facing front, move hand to the left -> x+ (LEFT)

Right glove, palm facing left, move hand to the left -> z+ (FRONT)

Result I wanted was always LEFT, independent of palm direction.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I edited the question for extra clarity

Comment: What brand? What libraries? What code have you tried? There isn't nearly enough information for anyone to answer your question. _Read_ the link I provided. At a minimum you should be showing the code that isn't working.